# xtea encryption arduino to webserver

Tags: encryption, arduino, webserver

Hi i'm using xtea encryption library on arduino. My code (part of it) is as follows:

```
XXTEA xxtea("0123456789012345");    
dtostrf(celsius, 4, 3, temperature);
xxtea.encrypt(temperature);
...
...
client.print("?temp=");
client.print(temperature);
client.print("&fahrenheit=");
client.print(fahrenheit);
client.print("&key=");
client.print("123456789012345");
```

The url that is sent to webserver looks like:

add.php?temp=\xcb\x17\x0fMQ\xc2\xb6?4\x06\xd1c&fahrenhei=72.27&key=0123456789012345

My PHP code looks like this:

```
include("xtea.class.php");
echo $temp1=  rtrim($_GET["temp"]);
echo $key=$_GET["key"];
echo"<br><br>";
$xtea = new XTEA($key);
echo $ausgabe =$xtea->Decrypt($temp1);
```

For ausgaben i get "¥K^4`". What is wrong?

The xtea.class for php got from here: http://www.php-einfach.de/sonstiges_generator_xtea.php

Comment: Is your `client.print("123456789012345");` missing a leading zero?

Comment: ups..i changed this to 0123456789012345 and still get no plausible value.

Comment: Can you encrypt and decrypt in the same function?  Without using URLs - just for testing....

Comment: serial.println gives something like; ‘¶b79¿"]×&¢¬

Comment: From what I know about xtea, you need to be aware that it deals in blocks of data...But that is not the issue here, you need to get encrypt and decrypt working - one after the other ...Before you extend it to the internet URL